# Overriding "endl" in C++ by #define preprocessor directive

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor, preprocessor-directive

I used the following code to override and replace `endl` with something other than "a new line".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#define endl "OOOO"  //replacing "endl"


int main(){

    cout << "start " << endl << " end";
    return 0;

}
```

Then the result will be:

```
start OOOO end
```

instead of:

```
start
end
```

But doing the same to `cout` causes errors.

**Why can we do this to `endl` but we cannot do the same to `cout`?**

Comment: What happens if you try to define `cout` or `printf` as something else?  (And to be honest, you shouldn't be doing any of this.)

Comment: The CPP, in some guise, 'always' runs first. Look at *that* result to resolve the question. In gcc, eg., use the [-E flag](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html).

Comment: Why do you think you can't do the same thing with `cout` or `printf`?

Comment: When I define 'cout' and 'printf', as far as I don't use them in the program I'm fine but when they're used in the program body it will make errors while debugging.

Comment: @MiladNasri It depends on how do you define `cout`.

Comment: Please edit your post and clarify the differences you are seeing, preferably with _correct_ example code and _complete_ errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It of course depends upon what you define your macro as, and how you use it. After preprocessing, this:

```
#define endl "OOOO"
cout << "start " << endl << " end";
```

becomes this:

```
cout << "start " << "OOOO" << " end";
```

Which is a perfectly valid statement. However, after preprocessing this:

```
#define cout "OOOO"
cout << "start " << endl << " end";
```

becomes this:

```
"OOOO" << "start " << endl << " end";
```

Which is not a valid statement. If you do this though:

```
#define printf "OOOO"
cout << printf;
```

That becomes this:

```
cout << "OOOO";
```

Which is fine. Likewise, if you did this:

```
#define cout "OOOO"
printf(cout);
```

it becomes this:

```
printf("OOOO");
```

Which is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

#### Why can I write a `#define` macro to replace `endl`?

Because you can write a `#define` macro for anything.  A `#define` macro is a simple search and replace that runs during the preprocessing step.

#### Why can't I write a `#define` macro to replace `cout` or `printf`?

You can.  You can write a `#define` macro for anything.

#### But my code doesn't compile when I write `#define` macros for `cout` and `printf`.

This is happening because after the macro expansion occurs, you're left with compilation errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are messing up two parts of the compilation process.

The first one, resolving `#define` is the preprocessor and a simple text-replacement. It doesn't care what you replace and is not aware of any keywords.

The second part is the compilation itself, where keywords are actually interpreted and given some "meaning".

In your example, the line

```
cout << "start " << endl << " end";
```

becomes

```
cout << "start " << "OOOO" << " end";
```

which is totally valid. If you try something similar with cout you will likely end up with something invalid.

To make even more of a mess, you can do something like this:

```
#define printf cout
#define if while
#define void int
#define delete(x) x++

int main() {
    void i=0;
    if(i<5){
        printf << i << endl;
        delete(i);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

which would become

```
int main() {
int i=0;
    while(i<5){
        cout<< i << endl;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

before beeing processed by the compiler.

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/xHeWyW)

**However you should never use macros to change the behaviour of well known keywords or parts of the standard library.** It makes code unreadable, a mess to maintain and will probably break stuff.